# Unique situation with RAM slots

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have this unique problem with my RAM slot.

I have dual core Desktop machine with windows 7 installed. I have two RAM slots which had 2 GB DDR3 RAM each and the machine was working fine.

Now I have got this problem and I did not get any display. When I start the computer with one RAM, it works. I checked both the RAMs and both the Slots indiviidually and both of those works fine individually, but when I install two RAMs together, it stops working. Can anyone suggest me whats the problem.

------------------------ } Slot 1
------------------------ } Slot 2
RAM1
RAM2

Slot 1 --- RAM 1
Slot 2 --- RAM 2
Does not work.....

Slot 1 --- RAM 2
Slot 2 --- RAM 1
Does not work.....

Slot 1 --- RAM1
Slot 2 --- empty
works.....

Slot 1 --- empty
Slot 2 --- RAM1
works.....

Slot 1 --- empty
Slot 2 --- RAM2
works.....

Slot 1 --- RAM2
Slot 2 --- empty
works.....

Please help me.

Comment: Do you overclock? Is the specific RAM type officially supported for this slot combination? Did you use a search engine before asking here? If yes, what makes your problem _unique_?

Comment: Have you checked your manual to see what slots *should* be populated and in which order?

Comment: What changed between when it was working and now? And do you mean you never get any display? Or you lose the display when the OS boots? Or what? Do the fans spin up?

Comment: Nothing has changed. The machine simply stopped working. The fan is running but there is nothing in the display.